# how can i use maven tomcat plugin for two different environment?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, configuration, maven, profile

In my tomcat project I have a configuration folder, in path `src/main/tomcatconf`.

Now I want to deploy to 2 different servers. A development server and a production one.

I run my development server with mvn tomcat:run. Running my server on the fly, and all work perfectly.

Now I want to add the production server, with a different configuration folder (ie `src/main/production/tomcatconf`) and deploy the .war on Tomcat instance in my filesystem (ie `/opt/tomcat6`) 
with mvn tomcat:deploy command.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i used maven resource plugin with profile configuration.

i've made two additional folder :

src/main/production

src/main/development,

then i move my Meta-inf/persistence.xml in these folder.

then i add this part of configuration on my pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>environment.type</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/development</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment.type</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/production</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

in this manner i've a common resource folder and an additional folder based by environment type.

Now when i run 
`mvn tomcat:run -Denvironment.type=dev` 
i use my development environment and when i run 
`mvn tomcat:run -Denvironment.type=prod`
i use my production enviroment.

The only drawback of this approach is that everytime i want change environment type i must run 
`mvn clean` to build the right configuration file.

Please let me know If you Think that i wrong or you want  suggest another kind of solution

Regards 
Antonio Musella